# Boundedness of Extremal

Tags: calculus-of-variations

This question was asked in CSIR NET December 2017.

> $I[y]=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}[(y')^{2}-4π^{2}(y)^{2}]dx$
>
> Let $(P)m= \inf\{I[y]: y\in C^{1}[0,1], y(0)=0,y(1)=0\}$ Let $y_{0}$
> satisfy the Euler-Lagrange Equation associated with $(P)$. Then which
> of the following is /are true?
>
> - 1. $m= -\infty$, $I$ is not bounded
> - 2. $m\in R$ with $I[y_{0}]=m$
> - 3. $m\in R$ with $I[y_{0}]>m$
> - 4. $m\in R$ with $I[y_{0}]<m$

**My Attempt**

Here the Extremal function will be:

> $y_{0}=c\sin(2πx)$

if we apply the boundary conditions. The answer should be the first option according to the answer key. But I am stuck around the boundedness of the extremal.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Poincaré - Wirtinger Inequality* $\pi^2 \int_0^1 y^2 \leq \int_0^1 (y^\prime )^2$, which is valid for any $y \in C_0^1([0,1]):= C_0([0,1]) \cap C^1([0,1])$, entails:

$$I[y] = \frac{1}{2}\ \int_0^1 (y^\prime)^2 - 4\pi^2 y^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}\ \int_0^1 \pi^2 y^2 - 4\pi^2 y^2 = -\frac{3}{2}\pi^2 \int_0^1 y^2 $$

with equality iff $y(x) = y_C(x) := C \sin(\pi x)$; therefore:

$$I[y_C] = -\frac{3}{2}\pi^2 C^2 \int_0^1 \sin^2 (\pi x)\ \text{d}x \to -\infty \qquad \text{as } C \to +\infty$$

and $I$ is unbounded from below over $C_0^1([0,1])$.

---

If you are not familiar with inequalities like Poincaré - Wirtinger's, you can argue as follows.

Functions of the family $y_C(x) := C \sin (\pi x)$ belong to $C_0^1([0,1])$ for each $C \in \mathbb{R}$.
Evaluating $I[\cdot]$ on $y_C$ gives:

$$\begin{split} I[y_C] &= \frac{C^2}{2} \int_0^1 \Big[\pi^2 \cos^2(\pi x) - 4\pi^2 \sin^2(\pi x)\Big]\ \text{d} x\\ &= \frac{\pi^2 C^2}{2} \int_0^1 \Big[ 1 - 5 \sin^2 (\pi x)\Big]\ \text{d} x \\ &\stackrel{t=\pi x}{=} \frac{\pi C^2}{2} \underbrace{\int_0^\pi \Big[ 1 - 5 \sin^2 t\Big]\ \text{d} t}_{= - \frac{3\pi}{2}} \\ &= - \frac{3\pi^2}{4} C^2\end{split}$$

and the unboundedness of $I[\cdot]$ follows by letting $C \to +\infty$ as above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but being a beginner I am unaware of the inequality you used. I had been following Calculus of Variations
By I. M. Gelfand, S. V. Fomin. Can you provide me with some reference for the inequality and some related examples so that I can tackle when it pops up in future?

Comment: Gel'fand & Fomin is a really good book, but is a bit outdated for it focus mostly on classical methods. There are many newer books about CoV you could refer to: for example, Dacorogna's *Introduction to the Calculus of Variations* is a good introductory book to the subject, focusing mostly on direct methods.

Comment: You can find a proof of Poincaré - Wirtinger inequality here on MathSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702168/proof-of-wirtinger-inequality

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha My pleasure. ;-)

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha I edited my answer showing how to solve the problem also when you aren't familiar with P-W inequality.

Answer (score 0):

1. FWIW, one way to physically understand the result, consider the Fourier series
   $$y(x)~=~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n \sin(\pi n x), \qquad a_n~\in~\mathbb{R}.\tag{A}$$
   OP's [action functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) for the [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator) becomes
   $$  I[y]~=~\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \! dx~(y^{\prime}(x)^2-4\pi^2 y(x)^2)~=~\ldots~=~\frac{\pi^2}{4}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(n^2-4)a^2_n.\tag{B}$$
   We see that the only Fourier mode with negative contribution to the action (B) is the $n=1$ mode. By setting all the other modes to zero, and letting $|a_1|\to\infty$, we see that the action $I[y]$ is unbounded from below, i.e. option (1) is correct.
2. Fun fact: We can read off the classical solutions/natural frequency of the harmonic oscillator from formula (B). It is the mode $n=2$ with arbitrary amplitude $a_2$. This agrees with OP's last formula. It is a stationary but *not* a minimum configuration for the action. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465310/2451) related Phys.SE post.